# Step Debugging SDL2 Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017, sdl-2

I have been working with SDL2 in Visual Studio 2017 in the last few days. However, I ran into a problem with debugging. If I press 'F5' to debug/run the program, it works just fine. However, if I press 'F11' to do the Step debugging, it gives an error saying it cannot find sdl_windows_main.c and giving me a dialog to find it. Is there a different way to do the step-by-step debugging, or is it not possible in combination with SDL2?

Comment: Do you really need to step through the first few instructions of your program as it's working its way through the C runtime?

Comment: Well, you could download SDL source and give VS the file it wants.